# Definite article for time of day

Tags: articles, indications-de-temps

"I will go to the cinema in the afternoon."

> Je vais aller au cinéma ____.

I think *cet après-midi* works for sure. What about *l'après-midi* or just *après-midi*? Does either or both of them work? I know that for days, the definite article signifies that the action takes place on every such day (*le lundi* = "every Monday") while no definite article means that the action happens only on one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Je vais aller au cinéma **dans l'après-midi**

Means **in** the afternoon, some time, you're don't really know when.

> Je vais aller au cinéma **cet** après-midi

**This** afternoon. It usually means you know when your movie is.

> Je vais **ø** au cinéma **l'après midi**

This means you go to the movies **every afternoon**. I used "*cinéma*" for the example but it would make more sense with something else, for example : "*Je ne travaille que l'après-midi*"

While you can say "*Je vais au cinéma samedi*", you can't say "*Je vais au cinéma après-midi*". Say "*Cet après-midi*" instead.

---

By the way you noticed I used "*cet*", but *après-midi* can be both masculine and feminine, you can say what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

> Je vais aller au cinéma dans l'après-midi

if you want to say

> Je vais aller au cinéma cet après-midi

it's

> this afternoon

Answer (score 0):

Je vais aller au cinéma ____.

- What about l'après-midi

-> Tout dépend de ce que l'on veut dire: ici ça laisserait penser que c'est tous les après-midi. Comme:

*J'irai au cinéma le jeudi*.

*J'irai au cinéma l'après-midi*.

S'il y a un contexte, c'est différent.

Par exemple:

*Je vais faire mes courses*

(on peut supposer que "aujourd'hui" est sous-entendu, car on parle au présent), *et

j'irai au cinéma l'après-midi*.

Là on sait de quel après-midi on parle, on ne met pas "cet".
Et d'ailleurs, "cet" réfère à l'après-midi du jour où on sommes.
On pourrait très bien imaginer un autre contexte:

*Mardi prochain, j'irai faire mes courses*, et

*j'irai au cinéma l'après-midi*.

Là encore, on sait de quel après-midi il s'agit.

- or just après-midi?

Non, parce qu'on n'emploie pas un mot sans déterminant (sauf cas très particuliers comme les jours de la semaine).
Je vais au cinéma après-midi ne veut rien dire en français.

- I know that for days, the definite article signifies that the action takes place on every such day (le lundi = "every Monday") while no definite article means that the action happens only on one day.

-> Voyons ça.

- The definite article = *Je joue au foot le jeudi*.
  " the action takes place on every such day" = C'est exact
- while no definite article means that the action happens only one day.
  -> Oui, par exmple: *Jeudi, je vais faire de la moto.*
  Ou: *Je vais au ski, jeudi*.

Mais...
L'après-midi n'est pas un jour, on ne peut pas le substituer à un jour.

On peut dire "Jeudi, je fais du sport", mais pas "Après-midi, je fais du sport".
Il faut forcément un article, ce n'est pas un jour.

Soit: *L'après-midi, je fais du sport.*
Soit: *Cet après-midi, je fais du sport.*
Tous les après-midis, etc...